# How could I have set the database application name in the title bar?

Tags: vba, ms-access

In Access 2016 a database "MediaMan.accdb" has the application name set ("MediaMan - Dev Copy") in the title bar differently to the filename, there is nothing set with VBA and the Options setting under Current Database for Application Title is "MediaMan". This is a personal database that I use at home, I have a development copy and a live copy. Of course i set this at some point in the dev copy, before cloning it as a live copy and forgot to remove the appendage in the live copy. For the life of me I dont remember how I set it, although I would have expected in the main form OnLoad(). By what other means could it have been set? (There is a backend db and a linked "interface-only" instance running at any one time)

Answer (score 1):

Do a global search in your VBA code for `AppTitle` and perhaps for `SetWindowText` if you used the API function.

Maybe you have an `AutoExec` macro that calls startup code.

From Online help:

```
Sub ChangeTitle()
    Dim obj As Object
    Const conPropNotFoundError = 3270

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    ' Change title bar.
    dbs.Properties!AppTitle = "Contacts Database"
    ' Update title bar on screen.
    Application.RefreshTitleBar
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    If Err.Number = conPropNotFoundError Then
        Set obj = dbs.CreateProperty("AppTitle", dbText, "Contacts Database")
        dbs.Properties.Append obj
    Else
        MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description
    End If
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunatly I already searched globally, though looking first for "Dev Copy" and then for "Dev" in case it was a composite. There are no macros - only VBA